# Customizing Web API Controller Parameters

Tags: rest, post, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-405

We have a Web API Controller generated from a model. The model has this form:

```
public class Pdf
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; } // File stored in AWS
    public int Job_ID { get; set; }
    public List<PdfPage> { get; set; }
}
```

The automatically generated controller has this default POST route:

```
// POST: api/Pdfs
[ResponseType(typeof(Pdf))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostPdf(Pdf pdf)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.JobFiles.Add(pdf);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = pdf.ID }, pdf);
}
```

In making a new `Pdf`, however, the file itself is put in AWS. In the case of hitting this route, where we're making a new `Pdf`, we want to make a new PDF that will be uploaded to AWS. In order to do that, we want to pass additional parameters to the route that don't exist in the model. Something like this:

```
// POST: api/Pdfs
[ResponseType(typeof(Pdf))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostPdf(Pdf pdf, double heightInches, double widthInches)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    // Make a blank PDF based on the dimensions provided
    MemoryStream newBlankPdfMemoryStream = PdfOperations.ITextSharpNewBlankPdf(8.5, 11);
    pdf.Url = await AWS.S3PubliclyAccessibleInsert("paragonpdfimages", pdf.Job_ID + "/" + pdf.Name, newBlankPdfMemoryStream);

    db.JobFiles.Add(pdf);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = pdf.ID }, pdf);
}
```

However, passing this body to the POST route:

```
{pdf: {Job_Id: 395, Name: "fds"}, widthInches: 8.5, heightInches: 11}
```

Results in a "405 Method Not Allowed" and a message in the body of "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'".

How can I accomplish this passing of additional parameters to the POST route? Do I need to make a custom route? If so what would that look like? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is caused by the fact that by default Web-Api binds parameters with a simple data type (such as double) using values from the query string of the URL. So you have 2 options:

- Tell Web-Api to get the values from the body by modifying your action to be

  `public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostPdf(Pdf pdf, [FromBody]double heightInches, [FromBody]double widthInches)`
- Pass the height and width values in the query string and not in the body.

  `....../PostPdf?heightInches=11&widthInches=8.5`

Comment: With the second option, how could I access those in the PostPdf method?

Comment: In exactly the same way you are currently, the model binding will simply assign the values from the query string to the action method's parameters

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get either of these to work. Still 405 errors. For the second instance do I need some directive for the model binding to bind the query string parameters?

Comment: Also, according to this [documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api), `[FromBody]` can't be used twice in the same route signature.